# How to say that you wish and make efforts to do something?

Tags: meaning, phrase-requests

I am looking for a short way to say that I wish and (simultaneously) make efforts / prepare to achieve something, however, so far I have come up only with candidate phrases which express just one of the two meanings:

1) "wish" group: *anticipate*, *look forward to*, *hope to*...

2) "prepare" group: *work upon*, *strive to*, *pursue*...

My last guess was the phrasal verb *look towards*, which initially seemed to me like an amalgam of *look forward* and *strive to*, however, Uncle Google disagrees with this assumption.

Thereby, I'm now left with no more ideas and would like to ask you for any proposals :)

Edit: A scenario, where one would need to use a verb with the above meaning, is for instance when wish to relocate to a new town and need to find a place to settle in:

> Hey, Renting Agency, I am from Boston and _______ to move* to New York (however, still haven't done it). Could you offer me a vacant accommodation there?

*If necessary, substitute with the gerund "moving".

Comment: Can you add some example sentences please?

Comment: Yeah, sure. I added one as an edit to my post

Comment: ***need*** seems to work quite well in your sentence.

Comment: Sorry - bad example. I gave another one.

Comment: These expressions are orthogonal. That is you can wish for something but take no steps to accomplish it, and you get prosecute some plan that you'd really rather not do. I think most people will assume that if you ask for help doing something, it's something you want to do.

Comment: In your new sentence, ***am*** as in, “I am from Boston and ***am*** [shortly] moving to NY...” I think you are overthinking this.

Comment: Yeah, my mind simply blocked after several minutes of thinking. Should I keep the question (in case someone else gets stuck with the same "dilemma") or it's not worth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An action you intend to undertake is a

**Plan** ([M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plan))

> something that a person intends to do

The example sentence would read

> Hey, sir, I am from Boston and ***plan*** to move to New York (however, still haven't done it). I need a job for this purpose. Could you offer me one?

Comment: Oh, I totally forgot about this option. Thanks. The only thing, which (in my opinion) requires some change, is the tense - present continuous better reflects the fact that you are working upon the goal you plan to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Even though you ruled it out, **strive** actually best combines both the meanings you are seeking.  When you strive towards something, you both desire it and are working to achieve it.  You wouldn't use either in the case you only wished it (but were not working towards it) or were only working for it (but didn't wish it).

"I am from Boston and am **striving** to move to New York"

> to make strenuous efforts toward any goal:
>   http://www.dictionary.com/browse/striving